# Detect when view controller appears from pop

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am popping a view controller deep within a navigation stack. Is it possible to detect if the view controller is being shown from a push or a pop?

```
nav stack:

[A] -> [B] -> [C] -> [D] -> [E]
```

[E] pops to [B]

```
nav stack:

[A]  -> [B] // Possible to detect if B appears from a pop?
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In view controller B, implement either `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. In there, use `isMovingToParent` and `isBeingPresented` to see under what conditions it is appearing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if !isBeingPresented && !isMovingToParent {
        // this view controller is becoming visible because something that was covering it has been dismissed or popped
    }
}
```

Below is a more general use of these properties that people may find handy:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isMovingToParent {
        // this view controller is becoming visible because it was just push onto a navigation controller or some other container view controller
    } else if isBeingPresented {
        // this view controller is becoming visible because it is being presented from another view controller
    } else if view.window == nil {
        // this view controller is becoming visible for the first time as the window's root view controller
    } else {
        // this view controller is becoming visible because something that was covering it has been dismissed or popped
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question.. isMovingToParent = true when it is pushed to the navstack because it is "moving to the nav stack" ?

Comment: @Mocha That is correct. `isMovingToParent` will be `true` when you go push B onto A.

Comment: A doubt: is it not `isBeingPresented` always `false` in this case? I mean, it can be omitted in this scenario, right?... Or if I am wrong, when it could be this variable `true`?

Comment: @ÁngelTéllez Yes, in this specific case it should always be false and omitted. I showed for the sake of completion.

Comment: Also this is not the case for root tab bar controllers. The condition will be true even when you switch tabs.